# How do I start a `spring` animation with react-native-reanimated in a declarative way?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I have a simple `Animated.View` that I move based on the user's finger, my component looks like this:

```js
return (
      <View
        style={styles.container}
      >
        <PanGestureHandler
          ref={this.panRef}
          onGestureEvent={this.handlePan}
          onHandlerStateChange={this.handlePan}
        >
          <Animated.View
            style={[
              styles.parent,
              {
                transform: [
                  { translateX: this.X },
                ],
              },
            ]}
          >
            <MyAwesomeComponent />
          </Animated.View>
        </PanGestureHandler>
      </View>
```

The problem is, I want to create a declarative method called `scrollToPosition(position, animated)`

It now looks like this:

```js
scrollToPosition = (position, animated = false) => {
    if (animated) {
      // TODO: What to do now?
    } else {
      this.X.setValue(position);
    }
  }
```

, it works without an animation, but my goal now is to add a way to animate the value with an Ease too.

If we were on the react-native Animated world, we'd do something like this:

```js
Animated.spring(this.X, {
    toValue: position,
}).start();
```

but how do I do the same thing with `react-native-reanimated`.
Please don't waste time explaining about the UI vs JS realm, I know about it, and I do want to take advantage of running animations in the UI thread, I just don't know how to run this animation declaratively after the user i.e taps a button.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In using Animated.spring in reanimated, you should define the config as without that, it won't work

```
const config = {
   damping: 15,
    mass: 1,
    stiffness: 150,
    overshootClamping: false,
    restSpeedThreshold: 0.001,
    restDisplacementThreshold: 0.001,
}

Animated.spring(this.X, {
    toValue: position,
    ...config
}).start();
```